# Specify full URL in routing middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have a NodeJS 5/ExpressJS 4 project.

My routing config is organised this way :

```
var routesApiAdmin       = require('./routes/api_admin');
var routesApiAdminUsers  = require('./routes/api_admin/users.js');
...
app.use('/api/admin', routesApiAdmin);
app.use('/api/admin/users', routesApiAdminUsers);
```

in */routes/api_admin/users.js*

```
router.get    ('/', userCtrl.get);
router.post   ('/', userCtrl.post);
router.put    ('/:userId', userCtrl.put);
router.delete ('/:userId', userCtrl.delete);
```

It works well this way but I'd like to have :

```
router.get    ('/users/', userCtrl.get);
router.post   ('/users/', userCtrl.post);
router.put    ('/users/:userId', userCtrl.put);
router.delete ('/users/:userId', userCtrl.delete);
//If I do this I need to query /api/admin/users/users/
```

as I find it more readable.

How can I setup my routing middleware so it doesn't remove the matched part of the URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the path "/users/" instead "/" for routesApiAdminUsers you should put the routing middleware in the same routesApiAdmin routing middleware